# Java splash screen flickering on Debian Linux

Tags: java, swing, debian, java-8, java-7

I have machine from a client that is running Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.4 (Lenny). There is a Java Swing application that runs on it that has a splash screen. We have been using Java 6 for years, but recently started trying out Java 7 & 8. Both Java 7 & 8 have issues with making the splash screen flicker on startup.

The application is using the standard SplashScreen API where in the manifest you specify a splash screen image like this:

```
SplashScreen-Image: splash_screen.png
```

It is of course possible that it's not an issue on newer versions of Debian, however that is the version that my client is using and it's not an easy thing to upgrade all the machines.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. The upgrade in JVM may be demonstrating a bad habit or mis-use of the API

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's using the standard java splash screen API, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

After trial & error, I have determined that the splash screen will not flicker if using a JPG image. Both GIF & PNG image formats have issues flickering, when using Java 7 or 8. So, if you have this issue, just convert your splash image to JPG.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in my Debian, using Java 1.7.0_72 or 1.8.0_25, on Gnome 2.30.2 on an old Radeon X300SE (RV370 driver).  For me, the splash screen is stable.  Could your symptom come from a video driver issue, perhaps?

Comment: doubtful this will be any help, but have you looked into double buffering? Had an issue similar to this a while ago and a buddy of mine recommended double buffering and it solved my problem.